# Using the result set obtained to query again

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

In the following query I want to use `ii.instanceId` (in the following query) to get `ipAddress` from another table `instanceinfo`.

```
Select ui.userId, ui.username, ui.userStatus, ui.organization, ii.instanceId from 
userinfo as ui left join instanceallotmentinfo as ii on ui.accountId = ii.accountId 
where userType != 4 AND userId != 1 order by userId asc LIMIT 0 , 10
```

After the `ipAddress` is obtained I want to see the collective result of theabove query with `ipAddress` column. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `multiple joins` to query the database as shown below:

```
Select ui.userId, ui.username, ui.userStatus, ui.organization,  iai.instanceId, ii.instanceIpAddress from 
userinfo as ui 
left join instanceallotmentinfo as iai on ui.accountId = iai.accountId 
left join instanceinfo as ii on ii.instanceId = iai.instanceId;
```